# What is ΔICC term stands for in datasheet?

Tags: current, digital-logic, multiplexer

This is the [datasheet](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74LVC1G157.pdf) of the MUX (74LVC1G157) I am working with. While I was doing the power calculation, came to the following parameter, ΔICC.

[image]

1) What is this additional supply current stands for?

2) What is the significance of this value?

Comment: The triangle symbol means 'delta' or 'the change in'. So yours means 'the change in Icc' under certain conditions. (The answers below explain the conditions.) It's not a separate current to Icc, its describing a behaviour of Icc.

Comment: As it says : additional supply current per pin. Vi=Vcc-0.6 suggests this applies to each input pin held high but not actually at VCC. There will be some explanatory note in the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the "additional supply current" Vin must be 0V or Vcc.

Note that ΔIcc is spec'd as Vcc-0.6V.

This implies the beginning towards Vgs(th) output crossover conduction currents which with thermal drift in threshold cause the nominal additional current to reach 500uA max.

Comment: Stewart, So for the net current calculation, following is the understanding. Total current,I = Switching current + Supply current + Output load current

Comment: Yes but NO this is an addon to supply current if the input voltage is offset from either rail. They spec'd the input at Vol typical outputs that might a pull up load. It is an unusual spec.  The supply current will be even more if the input is Vdd/2